# Java: Importing the RSyntaxTextArea library?

Tags: java, import, rsyntaxtextarea

I need to import the RSyntaxTextArea to a project of mine, but i can't seem to get it to work!

The homepage is at: http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/
And the download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea/

But when i download it i get it as a .zip file, not a .jar as a typical library would be.

I'm using netbeans, and i've tried rightclicking on "Libraries" -> add JAR/Folder. But when i try to access something from the project i can't import it.

I need to import the following:

```
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.*;
```

It's probably a stupid mistake by me, but i've been struggling with it for a day now and i really want to get it working. Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extract the zip you will see that the source code lies in *src/org/fife/*.
I don't use Netbeans but you should be able to import that folder after extracting the data.

Comment: I just tried (for the 999th time), and it wont work for some reason. It says it can't find the package, even though the package is clearly there! Have i missed something? I understand it's hard to help without seeing the error. :(

Comment: Another way to solve the problem would be to simply add the code from the project directly to your own project structure. That will work just fine. :)

Comment: Yeah that would be another way, but it's a lot of files i need to include then. I would prefer to get it working the "real" way, this is really bugging me now. :/ I'm tired now so i'm going to bed, hopefully i can focus better tomorrow! Thanks for the help, if you come up with an idea please drop another comment!

Comment: If you're still there, do you think you could compile it to a .jar file? I found out i can import and use libraries if they are jar files.

Comment: Yeah, that's no problem. But you could also just download the jar [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea/files%2Frsyntaxtextarea%2F1.5.1%2Frsyntaxtextarea_1.5.1.zip/download). This zip file has a jar file inside of it. Just what you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fifesoft/rsyntaxtextarea):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fifesoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```