# TextArea library for code

Tags: java, jtextarea, indentation

I was wondering if there was a library or something that could
indent and embellish a code in a JTextArea instead of an ugly
plain text ?

Comment: They are not ugly.. I use them all the time :(

Comment: I wish I could give you a +10 for that, that made me laugh, you're not helping though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How sophisticated do you want your formatting to be? `RSyntaxTextArea` is very nice but fairly heavyweight; you can instead get HTML formatting in a (standard Swing) `JTextPane`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for noticing this, I used it and it works perfectly fine !

Answer (score 1):

If you want a syntax hightlight, you could use RSyntaxTextArea, a text component for Java Swing. Check: http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/

Comment: That's exactly what I want, is that a library that I have to import or something ? Because when I downloaded the file I got a bunch of folders with the package inside but when I run it in my code using RTextArea it crashes saying : **Can't find bundle for base name org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextArea**

Comment: For me, I just added the dependency on pom.xml. Are you using Maven?

Comment: @nicnhus Can't tell exactly what to do now... I'm not on my pc. :(

Comment: Well, thanks for helping :) Maybe you can just tell me if you imported the download file as a new project or if you added it as a new library inside your project ?

Comment: I use Maven instead, so there's no need to do none of these options, just add the dependency on the pom.xml

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391861/java-importing-the-rsyntaxtextarea-library) for a previous answer to getting `RSyntaxTextArea`